# "I wonder what your thoughts on it "

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am trying to reach out to someone on Twitter to ask their opinions on a product they bought.

Does it sound natural & grammatically correct to say "I wonder what your thoughts on it"?

How about "I wonder what your thoughts are about this product"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder what your thoughts are about this product.

This is grammatically correct. The ordering feels a *bit* off to me – I'd prefer the “are” to go at the end – but that preference feels weak enough to be just my dialect.

To answer the first question:

> I wonder what your thoughts on it **are**.

The simplest sentence of this form is “I wonder what it is.”. I feel like it breaks down like this, though I couldn't possibly tell you why:

```
┌ wonder ┬─────────.
I        what ┬─ is
              it
```

> (I wonder (what it is)).

[jr_kim's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/251782/25775), “I wonder what **are** your thoughts about this product” isn't *incorrect* per se, but it's a non-standard dialect; it's not formal, written English, and some might consider it a little odd. With different punctuation to make it a question with a preceding subordinate clause, however:

> I wonder, what are your thoughts about this product?

it's perfectly grammatically correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with: "I wonder what **are** your thoughts about this product"

Comment: Thanks jr_km,  I agree that is the answer.  For this to be a great answer,  could you explain *why* the word "are" is needed,  and why it goes there and not (for example) at the end or after "thoughts".

Comment: Thank you James K for the comment. I am sorry if my answer was not great. I was aiming more for the "sounds naturally" and less "grammatically correct".

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Not to be nitpicking but shouldn't it be "I wonder what your thoughts are about this product"?

Comment: @Joji Quite right, unless you phrase it as a question, as in: "I wonder... what are your thoughts about this product?"